# jaxb element with complexContent, restriction and attribute

Tags: xml, jaxb

I need to implement JAXB for the following XML model

```
<OrderItemList>
    <ItemCount>2</ItemCount>
    <OrderItem Sequence="1">
      <ItemId>12345</ItemId>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <DiscountId>prm</DiscountId>
      <DiscountPercent>3.5</DiscountPercent>
    </OrderItem>
    <OrderItem Sequence="1">
      <ItemId>44523</ItemId>
      <Quantity>3</Quantity>
      <DiscountId>nil</DiscountId>
      <DiscountPercent>0</DiscountPercent>
    </OrderItem>
</OrderItemList>
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
16:15:28,564 WARN  [OrderItemValidate] [error] null : cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'Sequence' is not allowed to appear in element 'OrderItem'.
16:15:28,565 ERROR [OrderItemValidate] org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 24; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'Sequence' is not allowed to appear in element 'OrderItem'.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 24; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'Sequence' is not allowed to appear in element 'OrderItem'.

22:05:09,966 WARN  [OrderItemValidate] [error] null : cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'TotalCount'. One of '{"www.myapp.com":OrderItem}' is expected.
22:05:09,967 ERROR [OrderItemValidate] org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 17; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'TotalCount'. One of '{"www.myapp.com":OrderItem}' is expected.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 17; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'TotalCount'. One of '{"www.myapp.com":OrderItem}' is expected.
```

I tried the following ways,

```
 * <complexType name="OrderItem">
 *   <complexContent>
 *     <restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       <all>
 *         <attribute name="Sequence" type="{www.myapp.com}Integer" use="required"/>
 *         <element name="ItemId" type="{www.myapp.com}String" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         <element name="Quantity" type="{www.myapp.com}Integer" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         <element name="DiscountId" type="{www.myapp.com}Number" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         <element name="DiscountPercent" type="{www.myapp.com}Number" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       </all>
 *     </restriction>
 *   </complexContent>
 * </complexType>
 *
```

- ```
    <ItemId>12345</ItemId>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <DiscountId>prm</DiscountId>
    <DiscountPercent>3.5</DiscountPercent>
  ```

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to implement JAXB for the following XML model

---

**OPTION #1 - Starting from Java Classes**

You could start from Java objects and do the following:

**OrderItemList**

```java
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="OrderItemList")
@XmlType(propOrder={"itemCount", "orderItems"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class OrderItemList {

    @XmlElement(name="OrderItem")
    private List<OrderItem> orderItems = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();

    @XmlElement(name="ItemCount")
    public int getItemCount() {
        return orderItems.size();
    }

}
```

**OrderItem**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class OrderItem {

    @XmlAttribute(name="Sequence")
    private int sequence;

    @XmlElement(name="ItemId")
    private int itemId;

    @XmlElement(name="Quantity")
    private int quantity;

    @XmlElement(name="DiscountId")
    private String discountId;

    @XmlElement(name="DiscountPercent")
    private float discountPercent;

}
```

---

**OPTION #2 - Starting from XML Schema**

You don't need to generate your model from an XML schema.  But if you wish to the XML schema could look something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="OrderItemList" type="orderItemList"/>

  <xs:complexType name="orderItemList">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ItemCount" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="OrderItem" type="orderItem" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="orderItem">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ItemId" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="Quantity" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="DiscountId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="DiscountPercent" type="xs:float"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Sequence" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

I generated this XML schema from the above annotated model using the following code:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

public class GenerateSchema {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(OrderItemList.class);
        jc.generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver() {

            @Override
            public Result createOutput(String namespaceUri, String suggestedFileName)
                    throws IOException {
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
                result.setSystemId(suggestedFileName);
                return result;
            }
        });
    }

}
```